# Where do I find Mandriva netinstall?

Tags: linux, system-installation, download, i386, mandriva

Where do I find Mandriva Linux netinstall for i386? Do they even have a Mandriva netinstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I - You can download boot.iso (for cd) or all.img (usb) from [ftp.linux.org.tr](ftp://ftp.linux.org.tr/mandriva/official/current/i586/install/images/) (or other mandriva mirrors)

II - You should follow these instructions at this [mandriva wiki page](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/Docs/Installing_Mandriva_Linux#Installation_from_a_local_mirror.2C_hard_disk.2C_local_network.2C_or_the_Internet).